# Alternative for maketitle and titlepage

Tags: titles

Is there another alternative for `maketitle` than `\begin{titlepage}...\end{titlepage}`?

The latter doesn't work for me since I am working with the documentclass `article` and I dont want the title on an extra page.

In fact I just want the title in 12pt bold font at the very top of my document, under that my name, after that list of contents. But all at the very first page.

The main article could also start at the first page.

What are my options?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! what is going wrong with use `\maketitle`? please show your problem in form of small but complete document which demonstrate your problem.

Comment: You should take a look at the `titling` package, which provides tools to customise the `\maketitle` command.

Comment: The problem with `maketitle`is that the title is very huge and not at the very top of the page. Besides it is not as wide as the text body.

Comment: `titling` has tools for that.  With ‘at the very top of the page’, I suppose you mean at the top margin, not at the top of  the sheet of paper?

Comment: You are right :) How could I increase the margin in `article`?

Comment: Use package `geometry`

Comment: So far I got everything I wanted, thanks a lot. One last thing: Is it possible to put the date next to the author's name, seperated with a comma?

Comment: You can do that with `titling`, too.

Comment: And how? Havn't found something about this in the doc. Here is what I have so far:
\preauthor{\begin{center}\large\scshape\lineskip 0.5em\begin{tabular}[t]{c}}
\postauthor{\end{tabular}\par\end{center}}
\predate{\begin{center}\large\scshape}
\postdate{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick hack: simply place the elements manually.

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{text}
\author{names}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\begin{center}

{\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont\bfseries\@title\par}

\@author
\end{center}
\makeatother

\tableofcontents
\section{section}

test
\end{document}
```